# How to pass a vector as a reference to class in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

`k.push_back(12);` Uncommenting this line stops all the threads (no output is shown). When I comment it threads start showing output.

```
#ifndef DESIGNA_H
#define DESIGNA_H
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class B
{
    int & shared;

public:
    B(int & shared) : shared(shared) {}
    void run() { while(1) { usleep(100);std::cout << "\nB shared: " << shared; } }
};

class A
{
    int & shared;
    std::vector<int> & p;

public:
    A(int & shared, std::vector<int> arg) : shared(shared), p(arg) {}
    void run() { while(1) { usleep(100);std::cout << "\nA shared: " << p[0]; } }
};

class Thread_manager
{
    std::vector<int> k;

    int shared;
    A objA;
    B objB;
    std::thread threadA;
    std::thread threadB;

public:
    Thread_manager()
     : objA(shared, k),
       objB(shared),
       threadA(&A::run, &objA),
       threadB(&B::run, &objB)
    {
        k.push_back(12);

        shared = 3;

        while(1)
        {
            std::cout << "\nd";
            usleep(1000);
        }
    }

    ~Thread_manager()
    {
        shared = 5;

        threadA.join();
        threadB.join();
    }
};
#endif // DESIGNA_H
```

I have been old

> With A(int & shared, std::vector arg) : shared(shared), p(arg) {}, you store dangling pointer in p.
>   ...
>   Exactly, this is storing a reference to a temporary copy.

How to pass a reference of a vector to a class?

Comment: With `A(int & shared, std::vector<int> arg) : shared(shared), p(arg) {}`, you store dangling pointer in `p`.

Comment: Exactly, this is storing a reference to a temporary copy.

Comment: And you have concurrent issue as you write and read same variable from different thread without synchronization (`shared` and (also `k` once previous typo fixed)).

Comment: @Jarod42 please write the solution as an answer

Comment: @Jarod42 please also explain in the answer why is that a dangling pointer.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, I know I haven't used mutex yet. I will use them later. Please help me to solve the current issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's compare the declarations in `A`

```
class A
{
    int & shared;
```

*reference to* int

```
    std::vector<int> & p;
```

*reference to* vector of ints

```
public:
    A(int & shared, std::vector<int> arg) : shared(shared), p(arg) {}
```

*reference to* int, *non-reference* vector of ints

```
};
```

As you have it now, the *object* that `p` names ceases to exist at the ending brace of that constructor. It is a *copy* of `Thread_manager::k`.

You need `arg` to be a `std::vector<int> &`.